# Why is the Tailwind "dark" class variant not being recognized in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am trying to use the "dark:" keyword to change the formatting of text on my website when dark mode is enabled (currently set by the user's preferences). Yet anything I use, like `dark:text-red-500` or `dark:bg-red-500` does not work. Nor is it showing up in my CSS as something like:

```css
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  .text-green-500 {
    color: #10B981;
  }
}
```

**_app.tsx:**

```js
import "../dist/output.css";
import { AppProps } from "next/app";
import { ThemeProvider } from "next-themes";

const font = {
  subsets: ["latin"],
  display: "swap",
};

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <main className={font.display}>
      <ThemeProvider>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </main>
  );
}
```

**tailwind.config.js:**

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors')

module.exports = {
  content: ["./pages/**/*.{ts,tsx}", 
    "./components/**/*.{ts,tsx}"],
  darkMode: 'media',
    theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        "primary": '#2563eb',
        "neon-green": '#22c55e',
        "waving-brown": '#F4C641',
        "white": "#FFFFFF",
        "background": "#FDF3F1",
        "gray": "#808080",
        "reddish":"#E55C41",
        "black": "#000000",
        "blue": "#2563eb",
        "violet": "#7c3aed"
      },
    },
    },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/typography')
  ],
}
```

I have tried to use a `Provider.tsx` file that used "use client" to render the dark mode once the page is loaded, and other various debugging efforts. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does your `postcss.config.js` file look like?

Comment: Also, where do you have your Tailwind directives? I have my `_app.js` set up to import `@styles/globals.css`, which has my directives and CSS additions, similar to what's referenced in the Tailwind installation doc: for Next.js: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs

Comment: @EdLucas I was not previously creating postcss, although I just installed it and created a postcss.config.js like this 

`
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  }
}
`

Comment: @EdLucas I'm importing "../dist/output.css", which is generated through this command: 

npx tailwindcss -i ./styles/global.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch   

This allows me to use the tailwind utility classes. 

Additionally, in the output.css file, this shows up, but it does not show up in the browser

media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  .dark\:text-green-500 {
    --tw-text-opacity: 1;
    color: rgb(34 197 94 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
  }

  .dark\:text-red-500 {
    --tw-text-opacity: 1;
    color: rgb(239 68 68 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
  }
}